# Selecting that contains almost duplicated rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables. *price_code* table has a foreign key that references on *site* table.

```
price_code
___________
priceCodeID
siteID
price
```

and

```
site   
______________
siteID
operatorName 
country
```

I need to select the rows that, for example, *country* = "Peru" and have a *price* = 0 as I want, but in price_code there are some rows that have the same siteID and have the two validations.
I need not consider a row if the *siteID* has a price different than zero in any register.

```
SELECT s.siteID, pc1.price, s.country, s.operatorName FROM price_code AS pc1 
INNER JOIN site AS s ON s.siteID = pc1.siteID 
WHERE country = "Peru"
    AND operatorName = "Movistar" AND price = 0 
    AND pc1.siteID NOT IN (
        SELECT siteID FROM price_code WHERE pc1.price <> 0 
    );
```

Some data on *price_code*:

```
priceCodeID | siteID | price
_____________________________
1000  | 64  |  0
1001  | 64  |  100
1002  | 27  |  0
1003  | 18  |  100
1004  | 17  |  1
```

And for *site*

```
siteID  |  operatorName  | country
___________________________________
64  |  Peru |  Movistar
27  |  Peru |  Movistar
18  |  Argentina | Movistar
27  |  Bolivia  |  Claro
```

And my result might be:

```
siteID  |  price  | country  | operatorName
____________________________________________
27  |  0  |  Peru  |  Movistar
```

Comment: You have the `operatorName` and `country` column headings backwards.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT s.siteID, p.price, s.country, s.operatorName 
FROM price_code AS p INNER JOIN site AS s 
ON s.siteID = p.siteID 
WHERE s.country = "Peru" AND s.operatorName = "Movistar" AND p.price = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM price_code 
  WHERE siteID = p.siteID AND price <> 0
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=949c466fa97dfa91cc55bc5ca9a3e4f2).
Results:

```
> siteID | price | country | operatorName
> -----: | ----: | :------ | :-----------
>     27 |     0 | Peru    | Movistar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct. You need to change `WHERE pc1.price_code <> 0` to `WHERE price_code <> 0`. By using the `pc1` prefix you're making this a correlated subquery, so it's testing the row in the main query, rather than filtering rows to be returned by the subquery.

You can make it clearer by adding an alias to the subquery:

```
AND pc1.siteID NOT IN (
    SELECT siteID FROM price_code AS pc2 WHERE pc2.price <> 0 
);
```